# JMeter cannot collect CPU per process due to Access Denied error

Tags: jmeter, windows-server-2012-r2

I have setup server monitoring in a JMeter test. The setup is very similar to the one in this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44963404/7624566). When I am collecting CPU or memory without specifying a process, everything works as expected. I see the graphs with correct metrics.

However, when I try to collect CPU per process, for example with metric parameter `pid=8948:percent`, the graph is empty, no samples are collected and I see the following exception on the monitored server:

```
ERROR   2018-04-03 13:17:14.607 [kg.apc.p] (): Error getting metric
org.hyperic.sigar.SigarPermissionDeniedException: Access is denied.
: 8948
        at org.hyperic.sigar.SigarProxyCache.invoke(SigarProxyCache.java:218)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.getProcCpu(Unknown Source)
        at kg.apc.perfmon.metrics.CPUProcMetric.getValue(CPUProcMetric.java:35)
        at kg.apc.perfmon.PerfMonMetricGetter.getMetricsLine(PerfMonMetricGetter
.java:114)
        at kg.apc.perfmon.PerfMonWorker.processSenders(PerfMonWorker.java:280)
        at kg.apc.perfmon.PerfMonWorker.run(PerfMonWorker.java:243)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I tried getting the process by name, but the exception is the same. 
I run `startAgent.bat --sysinfo` and indeed the user has no rights on the process w3wp.exe (8948) that I want to monitor (The user does not "see" this process).

The [documentation](https://github.com/undera/perfmon-agent/blob/master/README.md) states explicitly that I do not need admin rights
 on the application server (Windows Server 2012 R2). The user already has **Performance Monitor Users** and **Performance Log Users** role.

So how can I monitor CPU per process in a JMeter test with user that is not an administrator on the application server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work this around by running Server Agent with elevated privileges, it could be done in 2 ways:

1. Using [`psexec`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) tool you can [run a process with SYSTEM account rights](https://specopssoft.com/blog/how-to-become-the-local-system-account-with-psexec/)

   [image: PSExec become system]
2. Using [Task Scheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614(v=vs.85).aspx) you also have possibility to start process with the highest privileges

   [image: JMeter Task Scheduler]

Given you run Server Agent with elevated rights - you should be able to collect CPU metrics for IIS process.

See [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) article for more information on using PerfMon Metrics Collector and Server Agent.